# Django mark_safe and translation

Tags: django, forms, styles, translation

I'm trying to test mark_safe and translation in a Django form. I've added style in help_text of a field in a form by adding mark_safe and everything works as expected.
However i cannot figure out how to translate. For example i have:

`help_text=mark_safe(_('<p style="font-style:Italic; font-size:10px;">Enter your first name</p>'))`

If i run makemessages inside .po file i see the whole string as `'<p style="font-style:Italic; font-size:10px;">Enter your first name</p>'))` for translation.

Is there any way so i can keep the style and also translate `Enter your first name`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say what is your full problem with so few information, but you should probably define only the text in help-text variable, as

```
help_text = _("Enter your first name")
```

and style it when rendering the form in the template (or better by defining CSS styled class), like

```
{% for field in form %}
    {{field.label}}
    {{field}}
    <p style="font-style:Italic; font-size:10px;">{{field.help_text}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```